# Is there an optional prepared statement in SQL for different specific levels of querying

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Suppose I have a query that returns the total monthly sales of individual products in my database:

```
product = input("Enter product column to search")
milkOptions = input("Enter milkOptions column to search")
size = input("Enter size to search")

import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
sql ="""
select sum(quantity*price), strftime("%m-%Y", orderDate) 
as month 
from customerOrders
WHERE product = ? and milkOptions = ? and size = ?
group by orderDate"""
```

Is there a way to query various levels of specificity without creating many similar queries. For instance, If i enter Espresso for the product, leave out the milkoptions entry, and enter small for size, could I return all Small Espresso sales. Vice versa for leaving out and entering other options.

Here is my database:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
| orderid |  product  |  size  | milkOptions | orderDate  | quantity | price | customerid |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
|       1 | Espresso  | Small  | Soya        | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
|       2 | Cappucino | Small  | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
|       3 | Cappucino | Small  | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
|       4 | Cappucino | Medium | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an additional flag parameter `0` or `1` for each of the columns, like:

```
WHERE 
  (product = ? OR 0 = ?)  
  AND 
  (milkOptions = ? OR 0 = ?) 
  AND 
  (size = ? OR 0 = ?)
```

- When you pass `0` for the `product`'s flag parameter (and **anything** not null for the column `product`) the condition will evaluate to `TRUE` which is equivalent to not setting a condition for the column `product`.
- When you pass `1` for the `product`'s flag parameter and `'someproduct'` for the column `product` then the condition  is equivalent to `product = 'someproduct'`.

Comment: Thanks. But I am having the same error sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 3 supplied.

Comment: Now you have to pass 6 parameters. 2 for each column.

Comment: So would I add another 3 input variables i.e. size2 = input("Enter size") as well as the first size variable?

Comment: No. These parameters will be 0 or 1. If the user did not enter anything for size, you pass 0 and if the user entered a valid value pass 1.

Comment: Like this?:   aggregateIndividuals = cur.execute(sql, (product,product,
milkOptions,milkOptions, size,size,)).fetchall()

Comment: No. Like this:  `aggregateIndividuals = cur.execute(sql, (product,1, milkOptions,1, size,1,)).fetchall()` where you change 1s to 0s if you want the column queried or not.

Comment: If you just enter Espresso for product and leave size and milkOptions blank, then the parameters must be: "Espresso", 1, <anything>, 0, <anything>, 0 where <anything> is any valid value for that column.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to condition the parameters -- say if you intend for `NULL` values to mean ignore that one:

```
where (product = ? or ? is null) and
      (milkOptions = ? or ? is null) and
      (size = ? or ? is null)
```

A caveat is that the `or` generally prevents the use of an index.  So, if you have the right indexes and want to use them then constructing the `where` clause as a string based on what is available is an alternative.

Comment: Thanks. But I have the error sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 3 supplied. Would I create an additional empty three variables?

Comment: @grimReaperZ . . . You need to double the bindings, so what is passed in matches the query.