# Is there a way to query SQLite db with a WHERE clause that doesn't always have all attributes set?

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, where-clause

I'm building a Java desktop application and use SQLite for my database.

I want the user to be able to see results from the same table depending on a number of combinations of parameters, but they will also have the option to select "all" for them.

For example, if I have a table of Dogs with columns Name, Age, Breed, I want the user to be able to see all dogs OR all dogs with a certain age OR all dogs with a certain breed OR all dogs with a certain age & breed.

Is there a way to write all this in the same function or do I have to build a separate function for each combination of parameters?

**EDIT**
I am updating my question with a photo of my sample database and the query I'm trying to run, suggested by @Vikdor's answer
[image: Database]

```
    SELECT * FROM Dogs
WHERE
 CASE "" 
    when null then 1=1
    else name="" 

END

OR

CASE ""
    when null then 1=1
    else age=""
END

OR

CASE ""
    when null then 1=1
    else breed=""
END
```

Neither using AND nor OR between the CASE statements provided the desired result.
For example, when I use OR and apply the filters to the last two columns,

```
SELECT * FROM Dogs
WHERE
 CASE "" 
    when null then 1=1
    else name="" 

END

OR

CASE "12"
    when null then 1=1
    else age="12"
END

OR

CASE "GR"
    when null then 1=1
    else breed="GR"
END
```

[image: Output with OR]

of course it gets the rows with dogs having age 12 OR having breed GR.
Also, when no filter is specified ("" as CASE parameter for all columns), there are no rows returned, although in that case I want to have all rows returned.

With AND, I don't get any rows no matter the filter.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. [Why is “Is there a way to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: Check this similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58779103/10498828

Comment: @forpas thank you, I kept searching for similar questions but I couldn't find one for the life of me;

Comment: @Andreas lmao :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SQLite CASE](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-case/) expression and construct it such that when the filter is specified, it is applied and when not specified, the `WHEN` clause returns `true`.

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM demo
WHERE
case "SQL"
    when null then 1 = 1
    else name = "SQL"
END
OR
case "Create public link DB"
    when null then 1 = 1
    else hint = "Create public link DB"
END
```

In the above example, replae "SQL" constant in `CASE` expression with the parameter that should be passed from your Java program (You would be using a `PreparedStatement` or a `CallableStatement` to substitute those params with values anyway, right?)

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it does indeed work for one column, but I still don't know how I could modify it to make it work for all the columns in my table at the same time.

Comment: The same logic of CASE..WHEN can be applied to all columns that can be potentially filtered. In case where no filters are specified, the WHERE clause is essentially `1=1 AND 1=1` etc., In case where a subset of columns have filters specified, then the WHERE clause will be `1=1 AND column = <value>` and so on. Are you facing any challenge writing these CASE...WHEN based filter expressions? @Andreea

Comment: I understand the logic but I seem to have problems with the syntax, in the sense that  writing multiple CASE statements results in syntax errors

Comment: I updated the example SQL to contain multiple filter expressions (I used OR in between, but you can use anything that fits your use case, in a complex expression) @Andreea

Comment: Works perfectly when written with OR.. although my first reaction was to write the case statements with AND between them (and I still don't understand why it wouldn't be AND :)) ) // UPDATE: when no filters are specified, no rows are returned, although all rows should be returned in that case

Comment: can you paste your query in the question, as an edit?@Andreea

Comment: Just did, hope it makes sense.

Comment: The first case is not needed at all, that is preventing all the rows from being returned when there are no filters. @Andreea